# Reading and writing xml using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I'm reading an XML file using Perl, then make some changes to it, write it again to another XML file.

My input XML looks like :

```
            <A
              value1="123">
                <B
                  V1="1"
                  V2="7"
                  V3="1"/>
            </A>
```

But the output I'm getting is in the form :

```
            <A value1="123">
                <B V1="1" V2="7" V3="1"/>
            </A>
```

I'm using the code:

```
my $data_xml = $xml->XMLin(get($xml_url),KeepRoot => 1,ForceArray => 1);
XMLout($data_xml,KeepRoot => 1,OutputFile => "Keep5.xml");
```

How can I get output in the same format as the output?

Comment: Is the original file formatted manually?

Comment: @Matteo   The original file is read using perl and need to written back in another name

Comment: Why do you want to? Serious question. XML doens't define layout as part of the spec. As far as it's concerned, all smooshed on one line is _exactly the same_ as neatly layed out. It defines 'style sheets', which cover formatting and layout separately.

Comment: @Sobrique   My output xml file is read by another tool. When I provided the current output format it is not able to process it. So I want the output to be in the same format as the input

Comment: Then your other tool isn't reading XML, and no XML parser can help you. Sorry, but that's the way it is. It's -probably- doing some line based keyword matching, which isn't the same thing at all. (Even if it looks like it initially)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to preserve the original formatting but you could try to reformat the output with tools as

- [XML::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/~pip/XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn/Tidy.pm)
- [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm)
- or external tools like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

Comment: can you explain how the data is read and modified using any of these modules